# How to get bibtex to include all authors in \bibitem?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using bibtex with the 'amsalpha' style.  I am citing a paper with many authors, and bibtex currently labels this entry as [ABC+04].  But I'd really prefer having all the authors there, as in [ABCDE04].  What is the most efficient way of doing this?  I'd hope there's some sort of 'max authors' parameter I can just increase.  I am open to using a different bibtex style if necessary.  As a last resort, is there a way to simply tell bibtex what label I want for this particular entry (other than changing the .bbl file manually)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer assumes you want to continue with amsalpha.  If so, download the amscls.tds.zip from CTAN, extract it and look for the amsalpha.bst file.  Copy a version into the top directory of your document to compile and *rename* the bst, for example into amsalpha-a.bst.

Code line's #1039 entry "numnames" defines how many capitals are print as label in the text, the next code line #1040 "namesleft" how many capitals are the maximum in the bibliography.  Increase these integers -- obviously towards the same integer, and save these two changes.  Of course, do not forget to invoke \bibliographystyle{amsalpha-a} instead of the system-wide accessible \bibliographystyle{amsalpha}.

My second answer to this -- if you don't mind to change for a numerical style of bibliography -- is to change for package like achemso.  This package provides an option "maxauthors" an easier (and cleaner) way to define the maximum number of authors for one bibliographic reference print.

Comment: I did this, but now I get something like [ABCDE+04], which is strange since ABCDE are all of the authors.  What does the plus mean? (and how can I get rid of it?)

Comment: OK, I modified line #1060 as well and now everything works.